# Sanskrit verses & English translations of references of Rama and Krishna from the Primary Vedas

Tags: vedas, krishna, rama

This [blog](https://nitaigaurangablog.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/lord-krishna-and-rama-in-the-primary-vedas/) gives lot of references of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna from the primary Vedas, at many places only verse number is mentioned. Can someone provide the full verse and their English translations.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar that was my question, so here it is different, I already found a blog with references, now I am just asking for their translations, how others have translated. This blog gives some references from 4 vedas, not just upanishads. At many places, only verse numbers are mentioned without full verse & translation.   I am asking for full verse and translation.

Comment: Ok , Just change the title a bit so that the question wont appear as duplicate.

Comment: What is your question? You added a blog which gives some references to Rama and Krishna. Do you want all of them? Use proper tags which describe the topic of the question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma what should be the proper tag? yes, i am looking for the translations in english, many are just verse numbers.

Comment: Then you are asking for a list which could be very long. All verses is a too broad question.

Comment: May be just compile the list of verses you are looking for translation and add it to your question. That way, scope becomes limited.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I will edit to add the verse numbers in the question itself to limit the scope.